# Gilgamesh and Lilith, two different books by the same female author

Tags: story-identification, books

Both books came out in the last 10-15 years or so (late 90's early 2000's) and both were written by the same female author (this is why I've listed both here under a single question).

The first book (told in first person) is about **Gilgamesh** (the name Gilgamesh is not in the book title) and he tells his story from when he was a child far in the past and continues to the present day and then into the far future when the earth has been swallowed by the sun and he is just a disembodied mind.

The second is about **Lilith** (name Lilith is again not in the book title) and on this one I'm much more vague on the overall story, sorry. I believe that this one is also told in the first person.

From what I remember, the books aren't connected as part of a series, they are both single self contained novels.

I got both books from the library (I read the Gilgamesh one first and liked it, so I looked for more by that author and found the Lilith one) in the past 10 years and neither book was very old when I got them. A search online just gets me books with Gilgamesh and Lilith in the titles.

Comment: Brenda W. Clough's "How Like a God" almost sorta kinda fits, but I don't think she ever published anything regarding Lilith. I doubt it's anything by her.

Comment: This is a hard one to research. With a gazillion references to Gilgamesh and "Gilgamesh in science fiction", the signal-to-noise ration is terrible.

Comment: Yeah ive been looking for these two books for years now, library no longer has them and they couldnt find em when I asked for help to find em. And your right about the signal-to-noise, its the reason ive finally started asking on forums like this, ive also asked the same question on other sites. Its not Brenda Clough, thanks for that though.

Comment: This is a long shot so I'm not putting it as an answer, but Brenna Yovanoff wrote a book this century called The Space Between which features Lilith as a major player (she's the protagonist's mother). Could it be that? http://brennayovanoff.com/the-space-between/

Comment: Its not Brenna Yovanoff, sorry, thanks for the attempt though

Comment: If you borrowed them from a library is it not possible to check your reading history with them?

Comment: I tried that, they couldnt help me, they only keep their lending history for a time then its overwritten by new book loans

Comment: The Athanor Series by Jane Lindskold fits the 2 books about Gilgamesh and Lilith by a female author and they have the right date range 1997-1998. However they are a series and they dont really sound like they have the plot you are looking for

Comment: Had a look through Lindskolds books but its not her. Thanks

Comment: Seeing this, I thought of Octavia Butler (for the XenoGenesis trilogy with Lilith Ayapo as the main character) but I'm not aware of any of her stories containing a Gilgamesh.

Answer (score 5):

This answer only fits some parts of your question, but Janet Morris had a multi-author series involving a bunch of heroes, including Gilgamesh.  The series was called *[Heroes in Hell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heroes_in_Hell)*.  It included the Hugo Award winning story [Gilgamesh in the Outback](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gilgamesh_in_the_Outback) by Robert Silverberg.

So..female author, about Gilgamesh, came out in 1986.  I can't confirm that Lilith is in there though.  Also, you said non-series, which does not fit my answer.

Comment: its not the Silverberg story, thanks, il keep searching

Answer (score 5):

Well Organic Marble has guided in the right track. The answer is Janet Morris's (writer and or editor) books.

Janet Morris' s [Heroes In Hell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heroes_in_Hell) project is a shared world premise of all mythical heroes and heroines. Gilgamesh is one of the many important characters in it. So is Lilith.

> Gilgamesh stars in - **"Rebels in Hell"** anthology. As showcased by Organic
>   Marble, **Gilgamesh in the Outback** by **Robert Silverberg**. Reference link of [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gilgamesh_in_the_Outback) for your reference.
>
> Lilith stars in - **"Poets in Hell"** anthology. **When You Gaze Into an Abyss** by **Matthew
>   Kirshenblatt**. You can refer to the authors page [here](https://matthewkirshenblatt.wordpress.com/tag/when-you-gaze-into-an-abyss/).

So in reality it is a multi author project headed by Janet Morris, who in fact is the editor. So the books have her name as titled *"Created By"*. All the books are self contained, separate novels and anthologies, just sharing the same universe.

The cover of the book Poets in Hell is given below -- [image]

Comment: no its not this, thanks though. They are definitely 2 seperate novels

Answer (score -1):

Not sure about Gilgamesh, but the English author Tanith Lee certainly wrote a book called "Lilith"

Comment: Can you provide some type of reference to support your statement ?

Comment: Its not Tanith Lee, thanks for the attempt though